# Swift convert string to UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>

Tags: swift, pointers, xcode6

I have a C function mapped to Swift defined as:

```
func swe_set_eph_path(path: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>) -> Void
```

I am trying to pass a path to the function and have tried:

```
        var path = [Int8](count: 1024, repeatedValue: 0);
        for i in 0...NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)-1
        {
            var range = i..<i+1
            path[i] = String.toInt(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath[range])
        }
        println("\(path)")
        swe_set_ephe_path(&path)
```

but on the path[i] line I get the error:

> 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with a range of
>   Int

```
swe_set_ephe_path(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath)
```

nor

```
swe_set_ephe_path(&NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath)
```

don't work either

Besides not working, I feel there has got to be a better, less convoluted way of doing this. Previous answers on StackOverflow using CString don't seem to work anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, when showing code, always show _real_ code. Your declaration is not real - it is not a valid Swift function declaration, and I suspect the function name is wrong. Do not type code into Stack Overflow; copy and paste _real_ code. Always.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Previous answers on StackOverflow using CString don't seem to work anymore

Nevertheless, `UnsafePointer<Int8>` is a C string. If your context absolutely requires an `UnsafeMutablePointer`, just coerce, like this:

```
let s = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
let cs = (s as NSString).UTF8String
var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(cs)
swe_set_ephe_path(buffer)
```

Of course I don't have your `swe_set_ephe_path`, but it works fine in my testing when it is stubbed like this:

```
func swe_set_ephe_path(path: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>) {
    println(String.fromCString(path))
}
```

Comment: That seemed to work great. It uses aspects of Swift that I was not familiar with, so for the answer to the question, and a lesson on more advanced language aspects, its a winner on both points. Thanks!

Comment: Delighted to help. It all came right out of my book, here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_c_data_types Let me know of you have further questions about what the code does.

Comment: Damn! I just bought and read that book but did not look at the appendix! I will now...

Comment: LOL! The appendix is about the particular problem you are facing, namely, interaction with an Objective-C API. Of course it assumes you've read the rest of the book, too; so, for example, the `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>` requires that you understand generics (chapter 4).

Comment: With Swift 4, this gives me:
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafePointer<Int8>)'

Comment: @agirault add `mutating:` as a parameter label to the UnsafeMutablePointer initializer. `var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: cs)`

Answer (score 20):

In current version of Swift language you can do it like this (other answers are outdated):

```
let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath
let param = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: (path as NSString).utf8String)
```

Comment: What exactly is "current version of Swift language"?

Answer (score 10):

It’s actually extremely irritating of the library you’re using that it requires (in the C declaration) a `char * path` rather than `const char * path`.  (this is assuming the function doesn’t mutate the input string – if it does, you’re in a whole different situation).

If it didn’t, the function would come over to Swift as:

```
// note, UnsafePointer not UnsafeMutablePointer
func swe_set_eph_path(path: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> Void
```

and you could then rely on Swift’s implicit conversion:

```
let str = "blah"
swe_set_eph_path(str) // Swift implicitly converts Strings 
                      // to const C strings when calling C funcs
```

But you can do an unsafe conversion quite easily, in combination with the `withCString` function:

```
str.withCString { cstr in
    swe_set_eph_path(UnsafeMutablePointer(cstr))
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of showing him `withCString` as a Swiftier alternative to `(s as NSString).UTF8String` - I actually put that in, and then I took it out again. :) - I have no idea why he needs an unsafe mutable pointer; I just gave him one because he said he needed one.

Comment: Aside from it’s pure-Swiftness, I prefer the `withCString` as it makes the scoping explicit.  I get very nervous about that `(str as NSString).UTF8String`.  When does that `NSString` version get destroyed, presumably taking the memory allocated to the UTF-8 version with it?  It’s not clear.  Possibly before you get a chance to use it...

Comment: Actually it was never allocated. It's just a way of looking at the original string. I trust the compiler not to optimize the original string away! Maybe I shouldn't.

Comment: Yah that’s what I meant, the memory allocated to the internal representation.  Strictly speaking, the refcount of the `NSString` is zero on the line following the cast and it could be destroyed there and then, prior to the pointer being passed into the function…

Comment: I agree it makes it more difficult with an unsafe mutable pointer. The call is actually to the Swiss Ephemeris library that pretty much every astrology programmer uses. More or less the same code base supports C, C#, Java, and now Swift, on Unix, Linux, Windows, OSX, and now IOS. BTW, Matt was not fast enough in his edits. I snagged the "Swiftier" alternative before he could delete it. It works too! I'll admit, not being familiar with Objective-C makes it a little more interesting coming from someone who has gone from Cobol to C to C# to Java and now Swift.

Answer (score 7):

I had a static library (`someLibrary.a`) written in C++ compiled for iOS.
The header file (`someLibrary.h`) had a function exposed like this:

`extern long someFunction(char* aString);`

The declaration in Swift looks like this:

`Int someFunction(aString: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>)`

I made an extension to `String`:

```
extension String {
    var UTF8CString: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> {
        return UnsafeMutablePointer((self as NSString).UTF8String)
    }
}
```

So then I can call the method like so:

`someFunction(mySwiftString.UTF8CString)`

Answer (score 2):

Update: Make String extension (swift 5.7)

```
extension String {
    var UTF8CString: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> {
        return UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: (self as NSString).utf8String!)
    }
}
```