# Use C structs in swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I am using a framework from a vendor made in C, this framework has the following struct:

```
typedef struct tTINFO {
    int size;              

    const char* vId; 
    const char* cId; 
    const char* cmm;  
    const char* cKey;
} TINFO;
```

which gets imported into swift as such:

```
public struct tTINFO {
    /**< \brief Size of the structure */
    public var size: Int32

    /**< \brief Pointer to a null-terminated string*/
    public var vId: UnsafePointer<Int8>
    /**< \brief Pointer to a null-terminated string*/
    public var cId: UnsafePointer<Int8>
    /**< \brief Pointer to a null-terminated string. May be NULL. */
    public var cmm: UnsafePointer<Int8>
    public var cKey: UnsafePointer<Int8>
    public init()
    public init(size: Int32, vId: UnsafePointer<Int8>, cId: UnsafePointer<Int8>, cmm: UnsafePointer<Int8>, cKey: UnsafePointer<Int8>)
}
public typealias TINFO = tTINFO
```

To which i tried to use in swift as:

```
var cI:TINFO = TINFO(size: sizeof(TINFO),
                     vId: "vID",
                     cId: "cID",
                     cmm: nil,
                     cKey: "cKey")
```

and it gets passed to the following function  in the header

```
public func TI(CI: UnsafeMutablePointer<TINFO>, _ Reserved: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, _ Flags: Int32) -> TT
```

as such:

```
TI(&cI, nil, initOptions)
```

Now the compiler gives me no errors to my code, neither it crashes when it runs, however, the framework when using this code in swift returns me an error.

My questions are:

- Is my initialisation of the struct correct, i really think this is wrong as i cant any longer print the contents of cI i only get pointer values? If it is wrong how can i correct it?
- i seen in several places that to get the size of the struct i should use sizeof(TInfo) others say its strideof because of padding but it still isnt clear to me when they apply as both return the same size.

would appreciate any help with this. Btw i am using swift2.3

Edit:

Thanks to the link shared by @AMomchilov in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30042714/999817) setting Each struct property as a CChar before passing it to the struct worked, such as:

```
("vID" as NSString).UTF8String
```

Comment: What's the error you're given?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30042494/3141234

Comment: @Carcigenicate the errors are related to the vendor, and it just returns a generic error unfortunately:(

Comment: Can you show us a C-language code using the function and the struct?

Comment: @AMomchilov thanks it seems that setting ("vID" as NSString).UTF8String before passing it into the struct works. I wonder why is that, as documentation and several posts say that would happen with the compiler:(.

Comment: @RicardoDuarte that's strange, I'll check it out. BTW, you don't need the explicit coercion to NSString. The bridging is explicit in Swift 2

Comment: @AMomchilov yes i know it is explicit, i mean i am not an expert in this section of swift at all, but every single post and documentation i have read mentioned exactly that:(... I am not sure why it works. If the framework was open source i would post the actual headers here, and my code:( unfortunately i cannot do that.

Comment: Oops, I meant that the coercion is *implicit* in Swift 2, if you have Foundation imported

Comment: @AMomchilov just out of curiosity what part of the post did u thought it was relevant to this question? As the struct takes const char * (UnsafePointer<Int8>) not mutable pointers?

Comment: @AMomchilov have foundation imported where? The class that uses chunk of code imports foundation and as mentioned in the question i am using swift 2.3

Comment: Most of it is relevant, it's a well written question. The bridging to Foundation data types happens implicitly when Foundation is imported at the call site. This means either directly in the same file, or transitively from other imports which themselves import foundation. For example UIKit imports foundation, so if you have UIKit imported, you also get foundation

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`utf8String`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/UTF8String) to get the necessary `UnsafePointer<Int8>`, null-termianted string:

```
import Foundation
var cI:TINFO = TINFO(size: sizeof(TINFO),
                     vId: "vID".utf8String,
                     cId: "cID".utf8String,
                     cmm: nil,
                     cKey: "cKey".utf8String)
```