# How to convert String to UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> ? Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

I've tried this

```
 return areKeysConsistent(
     certificate as! UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>,
     certificate.lengthOfBytes(using: <#T##String.Encoding#>.utf8),
     privateKey as! UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>,
     privateKey.lengthOfBytes(using: <#T##String.Encoding#>.utf8),
     password as! UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>
 )
```

but IDE said
-"string to  always fails.

What's the correct way to convert it?, Thanks

Comment: The problem is that a string is an array of Int8 (CChar), _not_ UIInt8. There's a typological mismatch going on here. It is _data_ (Data, NSData) that is made of UInt8.

Comment: Where does this `areKeysConsistent` function come from? Is it under your control? It's odd that it expects `UInt8` not `CChar` (`Int8`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift convert string to UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042494/swift-convert-string-to-unsafemutablepointerint8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you run into some complexity from having to work with C.

The primary concern here is the life time of the pointers you pass into that function. My code below uses pointers into the buffer of the Swift Strings. This will be an issue if the `areKeysConsistent` captures those pointers for later use. It's possible that ARC deallocates the Swift String, making those stored pointers become dangling pointers.

```
func areKeysConsistent(
        _ cert: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, _ certLength: Int,
        _ key: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, _ keyLength: Int,
        _ pass: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, _ passLength: Int
    ) {
    print(cert, key, pass)
}

let certificate = "cert"
let privateKey = "key"
let password = "password"

var certificateCString = certificate.utf8CString
var privateKeyCString = privateKey.utf8CString
var passwordCString = password.utf8CString


certificateCString.withUnsafeMutableBytes { certUMRBP in
privateKeyCString.withUnsafeMutableBytes { pkUMRBP in
passwordCString.withUnsafeMutableBytes { passUMRBP in

    areKeysConsistent(
        certUMRBP.baseAddress!.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: certUMRBP.count),
        certUMRBP.count,
        pkUMRBP.baseAddress!.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: pkUMRBP.count),
        pkUMRBP.count,
        passUMRBP.baseAddress!.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: passUMRBP.count),
        passUMRBP.count
    )
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer is above

Comment: @ElizabethHernandez Have you checked that `areKeysConsistent` doesn't let the pointers escape?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Alexander that solved my problem here is my code:

```
func areKeysConsistentSwift(_ certificate : String,
                            privateKey : String,
                            password : String) -> Int32 {

    var result: Int32 = 0
    var certificateCString = certificate.utf8CString
    var privateKeyCString = privateKey.utf8CString
    var passwordCString = password.utf8CString


    certificateCString.withUnsafeMutableBytes { certUMRBP in
        privateKeyCString.withUnsafeMutableBytes { pkUMRBP in
            passwordCString.withUnsafeMutableBytes { passUMRBP in

                result = areKeysConsistent(
                    certUMRBP.baseAddress!.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: certUMRBP.count),
                    UInt32(certUMRBP.count),
                    pkUMRBP.baseAddress!.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: pkUMRBP.count),
                    UInt32(pkUMRBP.count),
                    passUMRBP.baseAddress!.bindMemory(to: Int8.self, capacity: passUMRBP.count)

                )
                print ("-------1--------")
                print (certUMRBP)
                print ("---------------")

                print ("-------2--------")
                print (pkUMRBP)
                print ("---------------")

                print ("-------3--------")
                print (passUMRBP)
                print ("---------------")

            }
        }
    }
    return Int32(result)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (in swift 4):

```
func stringToUnsafeMutablePointer(message: String) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> {
    var messageCString = message.utf8CString
    return messageCString.withUnsafeMutableBytes { mesUMRBP in
        return mesUMRBP.baseAddress!.bindMemory(to: Int8.self, capacity: mesUMRBP.count)
    }

}
```